# rails 4 routes error with new controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have just generated a controller and when I try to access any routes with it rails just gives me a UrlGenerationError.

```
# Error message
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in NaturalProductsController#organic
No route matches {:action=>"home", :controller=>"natural_products", :locale=>:en}
```

The problem seems to be that it is using `{:action=>"home"` when my controller doesn't even have a 'home' anything. But I cannot for the life of me figure out why, as I am using `link_to t("organic.link"), organic_path` and even manually typing `localhost:3000/en/organic` gets the same error.

config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|pt|nb/  do
    root              'company_name#home'
    get 'about'    => 'company_name#about'
    get 'contact'  => 'company_name#contact'
    get 'products' => 'company_name#products'
    get 'organic'     => 'natural_products#organic'
  end
```

`http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes`:

```
root_path       GET /(:locale)(.:format)          company_name#home {:locale=>/en|pt|nb/}
about_path      GET (/:locale)/about(.:format)    company_name#about {:locale=>/en|pt|nb/}
contact_path    GET (/:locale)/contact(.:format)  company_name#contact {:locale=>/en|pt|nb/}
products_path   GET (/:locale)/products(.:format) company_name#products {:locale=>/en|pt|nb/}
organic_path        GET (/:locale)/organic(.:format)      natural_products#organic {:locale=>/en|pt|nb/}
```

I am using rails 4.2.0beta4 with kubuntu 14.04.

Edit: Full stack trace, as requested. The only parts that are in my app are the header and application views. I will go through them really carefully, but they do already work fine with the existing controller.

Edit2: I found the problem, made an answer with it. Also, don't need the full stack trace.

```
app/views/layouts/_bootstrap_header.html.haml:15:in `_app_views_layouts__bootstrap_header_html_haml__3398608881953314325_70155715867000'
app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:18:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_haml__2085176017777231976_43442360'
```

Comment: Is your controller actually named foo_bar? And your action actually named baz? If not, put in the real names - it will make it easier for people to understand and spot errors.

Comment: @joshua.paling I was trying to be [minimal, complete and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also to not put any names from the not-yet-launched site to be indexed by google. I changed the names now to be more descriptive and generated a new controller with the actual name of "natural_products" with an action "organic" to verify that my problem wasn't a one-time-thing.

Comment: Can you show more about the error and the stack trace? Which line is the error throwing? Is it in a view or a controller action?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will fix everything, but `link_to` takes the anchor text as the first param.

So rather than `link_to organic_path`, it should be `link_to 'click here', organic_path` or similar.

Comment: woops, I made a typo in all the confusion. I fixed it now and it still gives me that error message though. Even just typing in the url `localhost:3000/en/organic` gives the error. I tried deleting the controller, making a new one with different names, and accessing it directly from the route it automatically makes, changing nothing, like `localhost:3000/natural_products/organic` with `get 'natural_products/organic'` at the top of routes.rb and it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a header file with these links, and they worked well when I had just one controller.

```
%li{class: ("active" if current_page?(action: "home"))}
  =link_to t("home.link"),      root_path

%li{class: ("active" if current_page?(action: "products"))}
  =link_to t("products.link"),  products_path
```

... etc.

Now, when I added the second controller and tried to access it, it ran `current_page?(action: "home") with the new controller...

The fix was to specify a controller, like this:

```
%li{class: ("active" if current_page?(action: "home", controller: "company_name"))}
  =link_to t("home.link"),      root_path
```

I'm sorry if I wasted anybodys time, I should have followed the stack trace better to begin with... +1 to sealocal who made me see the error.